# HBase inserts dont scale even after presplit

Tags: hbase

I have a HBase cluster (1.2, CDH 5.9) with 1 master node and 6 regionservers, and they are linked with a 1Gbe network. I have been running PerformanceEvaluation and YCSB benchmarks, but I always end up with a total of max 15 MB/s cluster write speed, regardless of whether I presplit the table and randomize the rowkeys. I tuned the memstore size to 256/512 MB, increased compactionThreshold to 12, increased `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` to 8G to reduce compactions, but none of them have an effect.

In the presplit case, I see that the RS are all hit with requests from the beginning, so I can't figure out where the bottleneck is. If I disable WAL, I can get to 50 MB/s, but I would like to keep WAL enabled if possible.

I read a few threads online that discussed similar problems, but don't think any of them ever got resolved.